# Magento, automatically assign newsletter subscribers to newsletter subscriber group

Tags: magento, newsletter, subscriber

I created the newsletter subscriber group on customer group, so I can apply discount for them, is there anyway to make this automatic, when someone subscribe to newsletter he/she automatically assign to newsletter subscribers group that have created?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [magento.se]

Comment: If you want this type of works,your must have newsletter subcriber name(minimum first name and last name) and password().magento did mot create a customer with out the three field.And,without customer register, can not assign to newsletter sub. group....

Comment: amit is correct , because a user group can be assigned to register users only , so do you need to assign to registered users or the guest users also

Comment: both if that is possible, if not then just the registered one. So if someone is registered and then subscribe to our newsletter, he/she automatically assign to newsletter subscriber group that I just created. Is there a way to set it up in magento admin